# connected and disconnected attributes

Tags: javascript, google-cast

I am trying to get the google cast button described here to be created entirely programatically but to also be customisable in code when it comes to connected and disconnected colours.

[cast integration docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_integrate)

from the above docs you can see that you can set the following attributes to control the colours for both states.

```
--connected-color && --disconnected-color
```

As the button is created programatically, I have to use *setAttribute* or something similar to create the attributes on the cast button. However the -- characters at the beginning are causing an *invalidCharacterError* I was wondering if anyone had come across this?

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/up7ugfqd/8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your jsfiddle i created another fiddle with the api and it was clear that --connected-color && --disconnected-color are css variables. 
https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/up7ugfqd/10/

SO all you need is a global style for the chrome cast button.

```
.chromecast-buttonxxxxx {
  --connected-color: blue;
  --disconnected-color: gray;
}
```

Note: Its not possible to set attribute names with special characters.  You have to control the behavior through css.

[image]

Comment: if I could add a face palm gif here I would thank you @karthick